# 'xclip' vs. 'xsel'

Tags: software-recommendation, xclip, xsel

There are two command-line tools (in two different packages) to access the X clipboard:

- `xclip`
- `xsel`

I would love to know the difference between those two and hear a recommendation which one to use in which cases.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Both `xclip` and `xsel` can store text into [3 different selections](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Clipboard) (by default it is primary selection). From experience I know that primary selection is basically what you high-light and released with the middle mouse click (which corresponds to pressing both right and left touchpad key on a laptop). The clipboard is the traditional <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

By examining the `man` pages for both, however, I've discovered that `xclip` wins in one aspect - reading from an input file:

```
$ cat testfile.txt                                                             
HELLOWORLD

$ xclip -selection clipboard testfile.txt

$ HELLOWORLD
mksh: HELLOWORLD: not found

$ xsel testfile.txt 
Usage: xsel [options]
Manipulate the X sele . . . (usage page goes on)
```

Of course you could use shell redirection with `xsel` to get around that

```
$ xsel --clipboard < testfile.txt                                              

$ HELLOWORLD
mksh: HELLOWORLD: not found
```

`xclip` also wins in the fact that you can output the contents of clipboard to file (which is perhaps useful when you want to redirect PRIMARY selection , i.e. highlights).  `xsel` offers only output to stdout

Comment: So there's no difference except that `xsel` can only operate through STDIN/STDOUT, while `xclip` also can use real files there? How boring! Well, I made friends with `xsel` a while ago and can live with using shell redirections to files, so I'll keep using that.

Comment: Unless I've missed something in the man pages or there are some hidden features, that's really all there is to these two programs :) Both are doing good enough job, so I guess it's more  of a preference than anything

Comment: I installed `xclip` today and wondered if it was the right choice. Your answer confirmed it was because I'm creating file from clipboard to use with `diff` command. +1 Thanks :)

Comment: I ran across a post has an excellent wrapper function for xclip that may tip the scale far in it's favor. https://madebynathan.com/2011/10/04/a-nicer-way-to-use-xclip/

Comment: @dragon788 well, this is nice but question is about difference in usage of two commands, so I don't quite see how this is relevant

Comment: Notice that there is [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/898094/146273) that explains an issue with `xclip` not closing STDOUT. If you use xclip in a script or function that hangs, this is likely the cause.

Comment: `xsel` has fewer dependencies than `xclip` q.v. https://gist.githubusercontent.com/houtianze/0fa0fe8bc6fad382631fd38f511f2048/raw vs https://gist.githubusercontent.com/houtianze/7ba320bc250589fdd35ad4082e52133f/raw

Answer (score 40):

In addition to @Serg [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/705658/382931), there is a piece of information from the [Tmux page in the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#X_clipboard_integration) that can be useful in some *specific cases*:

> Unlike xsel [xclip] works better when printing a raw bitstream that does not fit the current locale. Nevertheless, it is neater to use xsel **because xclip does not close `STDOUT`** after it has read from the tmux buffer. As such, tmux does not know that the copy task has completed, and continues to wait for xclip to terminate, thereby rendering tmux unresponsive. A workaround is to redirect `STDOUT` to `/dev/null`:

Comment: This **not closing STDOUT** issue with `xclip` is a major problem if you encounter it. I wasted 2 hours debugging it. I finally switched to `xsel -bi` and `xsel -bo`.

Comment: Thank you! Finally know why I was having issues with `xclip` over a forwarded X session. Explicitly closing `stdout` and `stderr` got things to work as I needed (e.g. `somecmd | ssh -X remote 'xclip -i -sel clip -d :0 >&- 2>&-'`)

Answer (score 28):

Something else to keep in mind, `xsel` has fewer dependencies than `xclip`:

```
# apt-cache depends xsel
xsel
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libx11-6
  Conflicts: xsel:i386

# apt-cache depends xclip
xclip
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libx11-6
  Depends: libxmu6
  Conflicts: xclip:i386
```

Comment: I suspect most installations already have libxmu6 though, many packages such as xterm, x11-apps, and x11-utils depend on it.

Answer (score 16):

Use **`xclip`**, because **`xsel`** can not extract binary data from clipboard, such as screenshots. For example, save screenshot to clipboard:

```
$ maim -s | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png
```

Then save to file and compare output:

```
$ xclip -o -selection clipboard > 1xclip
$ xsel -o --clipboard > 1xsel
$ ls -go 1*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 11948 Sep 26 20:13 1xclip
-rw-rw-r-- 1     0 Sep 26 20:13 1xsel
```

Comment: I find that `xclip` isn't necessarily always able to handle binary data either, e.g. when using the "Copy to clipboard" button from gnome-screenshot I get no output at all. When copying an image with Ctrl+C from e.g. a LibreOffice Document, it only works if I manually specify the target type like `xclip -o -t image/png -selection clipboard`.

Comment: I don't get output from `gnome-screenshot` at all, but that's another issue - https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-screenshot/issues/14

Answer (score 2):

There is one other reason to use xclip over xsel – xclip can manipulate cut buffer 0, by passing `-selection buffer-cut`, which xsel cannot do.

It's relatively easy to allow it to manipulate the other cut buffers as well; here is my patch, though it's not well-tested and comes with no guarantees.

```
diff --git a/xclip.c b/xclip.c
index 5fc760cb7..eeb05f662 100644
--- a/xclip.c
+++ b/xclip.c
@@ -35,11 +35,12 @@
 #include "xclib.h"

 /* command line option table for XrmParseCommand() */
-XrmOptionDescRec opt_tab[14];
+XrmOptionDescRec opt_tab[15];

 /* Options that get set on the command line */
 int sloop = 0;         /* number of loops */
 char *sdisp = NULL;        /* X display to connect to */
+int bufnum = 0;        /* Cut buffer number to use */
 Atom sseln = XA_PRIMARY;   /* X selection to work with */
 Atom target = XA_STRING;

@@ -165,6 +166,9 @@ doOptSel(void)
        break;
    case 'b':
        sseln = XA_STRING;
+       if (XrmGetResource(opt_db, "xclip.buffer", "Xclip.Buffer", &rec_typ, &rec_val)) {
+           bufnum = atoi(&rec_val.addr[0]);
+       }
        break;
    }

@@ -177,8 +181,10 @@ doOptSel(void)
        fprintf(stderr, "XA_SECONDARY");
        if (sseln == XA_CLIPBOARD(dpy))
        fprintf(stderr, "XA_CLIPBOARD");
-       if (sseln == XA_STRING)
+       if (sseln == XA_STRING) {
        fprintf(stderr, "XA_STRING");
+       fprintf(stderr, "\nUsing buffer number %d", bufnum);
+       }

        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    }
@@ -276,7 +282,7 @@ doIn(Window win, const char *progname)

     /* Handle cut buffer if needed */
     if (sseln == XA_STRING) {
-   XStoreBuffer(dpy, (char *) sel_buf, (int) sel_len, 0);
+   XStoreBuffer(dpy, (char *) sel_buf, (int) sel_len, bufnum);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
     }

@@ -445,7 +451,7 @@ doOut(Window win)
     unsigned int context = XCLIB_XCOUT_NONE;

     if (sseln == XA_STRING)
-   sel_buf = (unsigned char *) XFetchBuffer(dpy, (int *) &sel_len, 0);
+   sel_buf = (unsigned char *) XFetchBuffer(dpy, (int *) &sel_len, bufnum);
     else {
    while (1) {
        /* only get an event if xcout() is doing something */
@@ -595,6 +601,11 @@ main(int argc, char *argv[])
     opt_tab[13].argKind = XrmoptionNoArg;
     opt_tab[13].value = (XPointer) xcstrdup(ST);

+    opt_tab[14].option = xcstrdup("-buffer");
+    opt_tab[14].specifier = xcstrdup(".buffer");
+    opt_tab[14].argKind = XrmoptionSepArg;
+    opt_tab[14].value = (XPointer) NULL;
+
     /* parse command line options */
     doOptMain(argc, argv);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me `xclip` will let zsh shell `exit` very slowly when using `guake`.

Like run command: `$ pwd | xclip -selection c`.
Then run `$ exit` to quit shell.

`$ exit` need seconds to quit.

`xsel` is good with this situation.

Answer (score 0):

`xclip` has this special feature to remove last empty line of copied selection where `xsel` don't have this option.

> man xclip

`-rmlastnl    remove the last newline charater if present`