# is it possible to feed highlighted text as input to grep

Tags: grep, clipboard

I use grep to find unique (marker) text among a large number of files.

```
grep MarkerText -r -C 30 -h ~/helpfiles/*
```

Is it possible to feed a highlighted text as input to my grep command so that the highlighted text replaces MarkerText in this command? I am hoping to avoid having to copy and paste all the time.

Comment: Hint: highlight what you want and then use Shift+Insert. That should work on X11, not sure if Wayland has the same concept of Selections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sure - there is `PRIMARY` selection in X11.

> PRIMARY selection, is used when the user selects some data. [X Window: Clipboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection#Clipboard)

You can use either `xsel` or `xclip` cli tools:

### TL;DR

1. Select some text

2a. `grep "$(xsel)" -r -C 30 -h ~/helpfiles/*`

OR

2b. `grep "$(xclip -o)" -r -C 30 -h ~/helpfiles/*`

### Precondition

- `xsel` or `xclip` package installed: `apt get install xsel` or `apt get install xclip`
- `X` server is running (i.e. you use X server, not text-mode without X server): `xset q > /dev/null && echo "X is running" || echo "start X server"`

### Explanation

Both `xsel` and `xclip` are clipboard management tools. Commands `xsel` and `xclip -o` print to `STDOUT` contents of `PRIMARY` selection.
More info you can find here: ['xclip' vs. 'xsel'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705620/xclip-vs-xsel)

Use double quotes around `$()`. This allows to highlight more than 1 word.

Comment: It worked! Thanks Yasen. I can now use this as some kind of a one-way hyperlink in pure text files.
BTW is there a better way of creating such links in simple text files? For example something like TAGS in vim. Thanks again

Comment: Some terminals can handle hyperlinlks and open `$BROWSER`. But I can't imagine a common way to use plain **text** as hypertext. Markdown maybe?

Answer (score 1):

If you can install xclip package, try:

```
grep `xclip -o` -r -C 30 -h ~/helpfiles/*
```

"xclip -o" in above command will get replaced with whatever's on your clipboard.