# How can I count characters of text copied in the clipboard?

Tags: clipboard, wc

I select some text and copy it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>. Now the text is in the system clipboard. I can paste this code using 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>v</kbd> in a file and run `wc` for the file to check the count of characters, lines and words.

But if I want to count the characters of the text in the clipboard without saving this in a file, is there a solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would need to release the clipboard contents somehow. Avoiding files can be done via a [pipeline](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172982/what-is-the-difference-between-redirection-and-pipe/1074550#1074550). For that there exists the `xclip` utility. It is not installed by default, so unless another program installed it as a dependency you may want to run

```
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

Once you install it, you can do

```
xclip -o sel clip | wc
```

Note that there exists [more than one clipboard aka selection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139191/85039) in Linux, hence why the use of `-o sel clip` flags. Of course, with use of a pipeline this avoids use of intermediate files as requested in the question.

Another side benefit of this utility is that you can use this utility not just in a GUI terminal, but within any virtual tty console by appending `DISPLAY=:0` to the beginning of the command (or the other appropriate display, if your X Window aka GUI server is configured for more than one display). See the related [post here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75141/85039) on that same topic. Thus, you avoid using keyboard shortcuts for releasing clipboard contents, and you can write scripts that use the clipboard in a more powerful way.

There is also another utility called `xsel` which operates in a similar fashion. You can read about it in a [related post](https://askubuntu.com/a/705658/295286).

Comment: result shows 0 0 0

Comment: Clipboard may have been overwritten or not copied well. It's OK, try copying text again and run the command

Comment: it's working now

Answer (score 3):

One solution is 'echo'ing the clipboard content and pass the content to `wc`:

```
$ echo -n "your text" | wc
  0 2 9
```

0 newline, 2 word and 9 characters.

As your text is inside your clipboard, you can paste the content in the terminal easily using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

Comment: Not if the content has shell-sensitive stuff. This is a fragile, and potentially dangerous, solution.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica somewhat safer: `wc <<'EOF'`, especially with bracketed paste.

Comment: Or just `wc` and enter, paste, then ctrl-D to end the text.  `wc` then displays the counts.

Comment: Unless there is a ^D in the text